# How to copy subset of a table from one database to another?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-9.5

So I have a table, person_table:

| name | age | gender |
| --- | --- | --- |
| john | 21 | M |
| abraham | 32 | M |

I want to copy name and gender columns of this table from one database to another on another server. So I have the following table in the other database.

| name | gender |
| --- | --- |
| john | M |
| abraham | M |

I tried to run the following command, but it does not seem to work.

```
psql -h localhost -d db_name -p 5432 -U postgres -c "copy(SELECT name, gender FROM person_table) to stdout" > dump.tsv
psql -h localhost -p 5431 -d leaves_db -U postgres -c "copy person_table from stdin" < dump.tsv
```

But I am getting this error

> ERROR:  relation "person_table" does not exist

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Also this is a dummy table. My actual table has millions of entries. Can anyone recommend some faster way to transfer data or my mentioned way is the fastest?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.4 and 9.5 are [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: The message is pretty clear, you're connected to a database where there is no table "person_table".

Comment: @FrankHeikens thank you for pointing it out. Is there a way to create a table dynamically if it does not exist?

Comment: Use CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS